# Please can I have a Power Query formula to allow me to check if cells contain some text and then replace?

Tags: powerquery

I have a list of residents who have different professions including being a student. However, some have written “Student” or “Overseas Student” or something else with the word student in it. I would like Power Query to search the column for any cell containing “Student” and replace it with “Student” so it removes any other references. Please can someone help?

I have tried to write the formula but no it have been successful.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [Text.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-contains) function, this will return a True/False, if the search text is in the column. You will need to then wrap it with a IF statement like:

```
if Text.Contains([Column1], "Student") then "Student" else [Column1]
```

[image]

Which will result in the following new column.

[image]

It's not clear from your question, if you want to replace items in a string with "I am a overseas student" to "I am a student", you'll have to use the replace & contains function, with a multiple if statement, to check what string you are searching for then replace that value.

Answer (score 0):

You can `Transform` the column in Power Query: 
*(You'll need to edit your M-Code in the Advanced Editor to add the `#"Normalize Student"` line)*

***Source***
[image]

***M Code***

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table7"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Profession", type text}}),

//edit table and column name to reflect your actual variables
    #"Normalize Student" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {
        "Profession", each if Text.Contains(_, "student", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) then "Student" else _, type text
    })
in
    #"Normalize Student"
```

***Result***
[image]